# How do I change the z coordinate of 2d objects in p5.js?(and other stuff)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to make a 2D game with a 3D like layering (For example *Don't starve together*)
Link: https://editor.p5js.org/TheDiamondfinderYT/full/pBfQMdgSd

But this is what I'm getting (walk to the "tree").
Two problems are immediate:

1. Duplication
2. Border overlay
3. The tree NEVER goes behind the square
   Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you're drawing the tree after you draw the square, so the tree will always be on top. You need a conditional to change the order of drawing the objects.

To solve your "duplication" problem, you aren't clearing the canvas on each draw, so you need to do that with `background(0);` (or whatever color you want)

To solve your "border overlay" problem, you need to use `noStroke()` to turn off the stroke.

Here's the full updated code: https://editor.p5js.org/Samathingamajig/sketches/b5NcCuioK

```js
// There's more stuff up here, setting up variables and such

function draw() {
  background(0); //  <===
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 30, 0, 0, playerX-Xdrag, playerY-Ydrag);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  
  if (playerY >= 110) { //  <=== here, you would need to make variables for the tree's location
    noStroke(); //  <===
    fill(255);
    image(tree, 30, 30, 100, 100);
    fill(100);
    rect(playerX, playerY, 30, 30, 1);
  } else { //  <===
    noStroke(); //  <===
    fill(100);
    rect(playerX, playerY, 30, 30, 1);
    fill(255);
    image(tree, 30, 30, 100, 100);
  }

  // More stuff down here too, but just some logic making the variables change
}
```

Also in that link, I changed some stuff (not functionality wise), such as adding semicolons `;`, fixing indentation, and changing `variable = variable + 5` to `variable += 5` and `-=` to the subtracting ones.

Nothing (with code) can be done about the tree's border except modifying the image to not have the border, since it has about 5 pixels of black border on it.

Comment: This helps with MOST of the problems, but one of the main things was the layering. You  can be behind it if it looks like you would be behind it, but you're in front of it if it looks like you should be in front of it. Say in *Don't starve together*, if your y-coordinate is more then a certain part of the objects y-coordinate, you are in front of it. but if you're not, you are behind it.

Comment: The trees border wasn't of concern, don't worry!